# Know if an image is similar

Tags: javascript, images, image-processing, comparison, image-recognition

I'm developing a mobile app and I want to know if you know any JavaScript library or similar to compare two images.

I need to apply a search for similar images after the user takes an image with the cell phone.

For example I have a wine label stored in my DB and I need that after the user takes a photo with the device a search is performed and look if the image taken by the user is similar to one in the DB.

The purpose of this is to search if the label exists and if exists print the product information.

Comment: According to my understanding this will hardly work in JavaScript. Wouldn't that require that all the images are available on the client (the phone) for comparing them? This would require a full DB download in the worst case. I could imagine something more intelligent, e.g. the client side generates some kind of reduced image (e.g. 40x30 pixels), sends that to the server and the server then requests more details if there are multiple matches. That would require a client and a server side library and we would need to know what the server side programming language is.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I took the first sentence and did a google search on it and in the results was a link to the Software Recommendations site showing that exact sentence, but from four days ago. I suspect that the question was asked previously, didn't get a response, removed, and asked again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to find the JavaScript with **Image Template Matching** here is link that give enough source for your project

[Resemble.js](https://github.com/Huddle/Resemble.js)

If you using Android than also go for OpenCV in android that will helps you a lot and provide flexibility